# Add view outside of onCreate in android

Tags: android

How can I add view bye function, outside of `onCreate()` in Android ?

**My MainActivity.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    static RelativeLayout mainRel;
    static LinearLayout ll;
    static TextView title;
    static Context context;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        RelativeLayout mainRel=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainRel);
    }

    public static void refresh(){
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); // actually "this" just works in onCreate;
            TextView title = new TextView(this);// actually "this" just works in onCreate;
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.addView(title);
            title.setText("TV");
            mainRel.addView(ll);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that refresh() method static?

Comment: because i need to call it from another class which has AsyncTask and refreshes the data and also views in this activity...

Answer (score 3):

Usually, UI-related operations are not done in `static` methods. If you remove the `static` keyword, the `this` pointer will work even outside `onCreate()`.

If you insist on keeping the `static` keyword (because you need the method to be static) then, you should pass a `Context` parameter to the method, by changing it to `refresh(Context context)`

**Edit:** if you need to call this method from another class, you might want to create a reference to your `Main` Activity and pass it to this other class, then call `myMainActivity.refresh()`

Comment: Can you post the edited code, including my suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Calling static method is really bad idea.

Instead you can provide reference of the `Activity` to your `AsyncTask` in constructor. Then call non-static `refresh()` method from AsyncTask#onPostExecute().

When you store reference to Activity in AsyncTask use WeakReference. In case your activity is destroyed while background task is working, it won't be held in memory till background ends.

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakRefrence<Main> mainRef;
    public YourAsyncTask(Main activity) {
        mainRef = new WeakReference<Main>(activity);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Main main = mainRef.get();
        if (main != null) {
            main.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```